# Ember 2.x get model's relationships at subroute of that model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Imagine that I have two models, Author and Book.

```
// models/author.js
DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  books: DS.hasMany('book')
});


// models/book.js
DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr(),
  author: DS.belongsTo('author')
})
```

It would be nice to have an endpoint at
`/api/authors/{authorID}/books` to be able to get all of the authors books in one batch request, instead of making multiple calls to `/api/books/{bookID}`, but it doesn't seem that ember supports this. It is possible to do `/api/books?authorID={authorID}`, but that would lose some of the benefits of the `store`.

Is there an Ember idiomatic way of doing `/api/authors/{authorID}/books`? Again, the goal is to be able to make one batch request to get all books for an author instead of making one call for every book in the author's `hasMany` list.

For a little more context, I have the following routes structure:

```
// router.js
...
this.route('authors', function() {
  this.route('author', { path: ':id' }, function() {
    this.route('books');
  });
});
...
```

In the 'authors' route I will load all of the authors. I do not want to synchronously load their related books, yet, as the list is potentially massive and not used on this route.

In the `author` route I'm using data of the author already retrieved (the name, in this case).

In the `books` route I would like to finally load all of the author's related books without needing to send a single request per book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `modelFor()` in the books route, you can `get()` the books for a single author.

**authors author route**

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.find('author', params.id); 
}
```

**authors author books route**

```
model() {
  var author = this.modelFor('authors.show');
  return author.get('books');
}
```

Here's an ember-twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/924dd7d31e0984b708f9

Comment: Thanks for the response. One could simply `return author.get('books')`, since `hasMany` relationships are promises. This will still make a single call per book, though, to `/api/books/{bookID}`. Your approach is, essentially, the one that I'm taking, and I think the best way to go about this.

Comment: Good point on simply returning `author.get('books')`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is for [RestAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#property_coalesceFindRequests) but it's quite ugly. The query is then `/api/books?ids[]=1&ids[]=2`. But if you know you will need all authors books you can sideload them and when you call `author.get('books')` it won't trigger fetch anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'd prefer not to sideload the data when loading authors as my dataset is massive. You're right that the RestAdapter solution is a bit ugly, too.